# Drag to move at unity and hold touch to keep moving at same direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, touch

So im trying to write a code to move player with dragging on screen but i want player to keep moving at same direction when i hold my finger and only stops when i take my finger away.
ive written this code and player moves but it stops when i hold my finger.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(
                transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * speedModifier,
                transform.position.y,
                transform.position.z + touch.deltaPosition.y * speedModifier);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How fast should your object move? In which direction? If you hold the touch there won't be any `deltaPosition` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you could store the last swipe movement and use it also for a stationary touch like e.g.

```
Vector2 currentDirection;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        switch (touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                currentDirection = touch.deltaPosition * speedModifier;
                transform.position += currentDirection;
                break;

           case TouchPhase.Stationary:
               transform.position += currentDirection;
               break;

           default:
               currentDirection = Vector2.zero; 
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

This way it continuous to move with the last swipe velocity.

However, in general you should also take the `Time.deltaTime` into account to be frame-rate independent.